# IBrokers - Download all position information

Tags: r, ibrokers

I am using the IBrokers API in R to try to download my current positions in my portfolio on Interactive Brokers.  However, I'm having trouble downloading the information by following the API documentation.

I can get this far with the following.  This downloads my account information, but it's not a desireable format.

```
tws <- twsConnect()
reqAccountUpdates(tws)
```

I trade using the following, but it doesn't work.

```
twsPortfolioValue(tws)
```

Ideally, I want a data frame that has the following fields: ticker, shares, execution price.

Is anyone familiar with this API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a `twsconn` object to `twsPortfolioValue`, but the function needs the output of `reqAccountUpdates` as its input, as explained in the Details section of `?twsPortfolioValue`

Try this:

```
ac <- reqAccountUpdates(tws)
twsPortfolioValue(ac)
```